# SQL : Get last 3 month data (with only available data in the column), not from current month or today?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Anyone help me out on this scenario. I need to get a last 3 month data from particular column, which is not from current date but only from available date.

Ex :

I have one Table named `Shop` and column named `OrderDate`, In `OrderDate` i have only dates until `30-06-2017`, but today's date is `07-02-2018`. From this i need to get last 3 months data, which is Jun'17, May'17 and Apr'17.

If data available in till July'17 means i need result Jul'17,Jun'17 & May'17. And so on.

Any can help on this to achieve in SQL ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your final data need to look like? For example, are you trying to get the past 3 months' data for *every* row in the `Shop` table (with the 3 months being defined relative to each row's `OrderDate`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that column `OrderDate` is of `date` or `datetime` datatype.

```
select * from Shop 
where OrderDate >
    (select dateadd(month, -3, max(OrderDate)) from Shop)
```

Comment: Thank you Michal. It works fine. Do you have any idea about same in Tableau calculation?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Ok Michal. That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get this is to select the largest date in that table and use that to create the filter.

So;

```
Select * 
from table 
where date >
Dateadd
('m', -3, 
( Select Max (date) from table)
)
```

Apologies in advance for poor formatting

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the maximum date in the table and use that:

```
select s.*
from Shop s,
(select convert(date, 
                format(
                  dateadd(MONTH, -3, max(OrderDate)), 'yyyyMM01')
                 ,112) as fromDate from Shop) md 
where s.OrderDate >= md.fromDate
```